# How to resize a FloatingActionButton in Android Java

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

I've been trying to create a `FloatingActionButton` with text, but I've been unable to:

- set the color of the text in the button
- set the color of the button
- set the size of the text in the button
- set the size of the button

When I make the text too small it becomes blurry.

My attempts below don't work.

What might I be getting wrong?

```
//method to convert text to image
public Bitmap textAsBitmap(String text, float textSize, int textColor) {
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    int textSize = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, textSize, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    paint.setColor(textColor);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    float baseline = -paint.ascent(); // ascent() is negative

    Typeface plain = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.font_awesome_free_solid);

    paint.setTypeface(plain);

    int width = (int) (paint.measureText(text) + 0.0f); // round
    int height = (int) (baseline + paint.descent() + 0.0f);
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, baseline, paint);
    return image;
}

FloatingActionButton fab = getFloatingActionBtn(this);
fab.setLayoutParams(fabLayoutParams);
fab.setImageBitmap(textAsBitmap("rotate", 20, Color.WHITE));
fab.setSize(FloatingActionButton.SIZE_MINI);

public FloatingActionButton getFloatingActionBtn(Context context) {
    FloatingActionButton fab = new FloatingActionButton(context);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mWebview.loadUrl( "javascript:window.location.reload( true )" );
        }
    });
    return fab;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the button color (backgroundTint) and size (layout_width/height) in the XML.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/Photo"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="#EF9A9A"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
```

About the text properties, it's weird to make a FAB have text, but you should check the XML too. Look for the android:Text tag and the give it the properties you want.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer, but I'm looking for a way to do it in Java